# Use variable on left size of variable declaration without Eval()

Tags: javascript, variables, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to do something like this but without `exec()`:

```
let variablename = "myVar"

exec(`let ${variablename} = 'foo'`)

console.log(myVar)
//output: "foo"
```

Unfortunately in Javscript I cannot include variables on the left side of definitions

This won't work:

```
let variablename = "myVar"

let `${variablename}` = 'foo'

console.log(myVar)
//output: "foo"
```

I know I could use an object but I wanted to ask if there's a more direct way that would allow `myVar` to be defined as a global variable.

I'm using this in a google chrome and firefox extention, so I need this to be compatable with google chrome Manifest v3 for extentions

Thank you to all answers!

Comment: why do you need this? why not take an object (with dynamic keys) instead?

Comment: "*I know I could use an object*" - then do that!

Comment: It's not clear what this has to do with browser extensions. Are you doing this in the code of your extension, or do you want to do that in a content script to define a global variable in the current page?